# Executing perl on xampp using eclipse

Tags: eclipse, perl, xampp

I have installed EPIC plugin to my eclipse kepler and it is installed in directory `C:\xampp`
But when i create a new projects from the eclipse and when i try to execute it , iam getting the following error as in screen shot below

[image]

Can anyone Please help  me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Problem is the Shebang. You use Windows, and an Xampp Server, so you need to say in your Shebang, that the Perlinterpreter is under `#!"C:\xampp\perl\bin\perl.exe"`

So all of your scripts need to start with

```
#!"C:\xampp\perl\bin\perl.exe"
```

instead of

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
```

EDIT:

As an example you could try to check the files under `C:\xampp\cgi-bin\`

Comment: If i try to add the shebang line you suggested then iam getting this error  The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.

Error message:
Premature end of script headers: test.pl

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Comment: what is the shebang of the example scripts?

Comment: #!"C:\xampp\perl\bin\perl.exe"

Comment: And you wrote the content-type right? `print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";`

Comment: #!"C:\xampp\perl\bin\perl.exe"

print "Helo Amit"; This is my test.pl file

Comment: you need to add the Content-type. Try this: 
`#!"C:\xampp\perl\bin\perl.exe" 
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"; 
print "Helo Amit";`